# Remove facebook permissions dialogs from my ANDROID app while sharing contents?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook SDK in my ANDROID app for sharing functionality,and as per facebook guidline it will asks for permissions before sharing anything if user doesn't grant it before.

so,does there any way to remove that permissions dialog or if it can handle it in background without showing it over the my android app??

Note:for FB SDK integration I am not using webview dialog or FB dialog , I have implemented my own dialog view for sharing and I am sharing with installed Native FB App.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it's against the Facebook policy to post on the user's behalf without their explicit permission to access their data.

> You may use Account Information in accordance with your privacy policy and other Facebook policies. All other data may only be used outside your app after you have obtained explicit user consent.

[See policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy).